# Manually set variable which is later called in play but expecting stdout

Tags: ansible

I have a rather large playbook where occasionally we need to run it 2x, but I'd like to be able to set a variable manually on the 2nd run (because during the play the variable has changed).

The problem I have is that the playbook is expecting the variable to have stdout because typically I gather this variable earlier in the playbook. So if I add the variable manually using the --extra-vars flag during my run I get an error `'str object' has no attribute 'stdout'`.

```
% ansible-playbook -bK -i ./hostlist.txt test-ansible-pb.yml --extra-vars "test=1"

fatal: [somehost.xyz.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'test.stdout|int >= 1' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (test.stdout|int >= 1): 'str object' has no attribute 'stdout'. 'str object' has no attribute 'stdout'
```

Is there a way to set the variable manually so it would pass the conditional check? I know I can change the conditional check however during the first run of the playbook that variable would have stdout.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The variables obviously don't survive between the playbook runs.

You have 2 options:

- set the variable via `--extra-vars` properly with all the fields, something like `--extra-vars test['stdout']=something` in the simplest case. But it's not a trivial task in case of a complex variable structure (also, Ansible dict merge settings will affect the behavior)
- in your playbook, save that variable into a file:

  ```yaml
  - name: Save the var to a file
    copy:
      dest: file.yaml
      content: "{{ test | to_yaml }}"
  ```

  And then pass the whole file to extra vars:

  ```
  ansible-playbook ... --extra-vars @file.yaml
  ```

But the goal itself seems to be a consequence of some playbook design issues.
If you add more details it would be possible to suggest a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Is there a way to set the variable manually so it would pass the conditional check?"***

A: No. It's not possible. Take a look at [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). The `extra vars` is the top precedence. It's not possible to override `extra vars`.

---

An option would be to use other variable and set the default value. For example, the below play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    test: "{'stdout': {{ stdout|default(0) }} }"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: test
    - debug:
        msg: test.stdout is bigger than 1
      when: test.stdout|int > 1
```

by default, gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
ok: [localhost] =>
  test:
    stdout: 0
  ...
skipping: [localhost]
```

Declare the extra variable

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e stdout=2
  ...
ok: [localhost] => 
  test:
    stdout: 2
  ...
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: test.stdout is bigger than 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use logic like this:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - when: >
        test_data is undefined
      block:
        - name: run command to get test data
          shell: echo $(( RANDOM % 2 ))
          register: test_cmd

        - set_fact:
            test_data: "{{ test_cmd.stdout }}"


    - when: >
        test_data|int >= 1
      debug:
        msg: "Your task goes here."
```

If `test_data` is not set when the playbook runs, we run a command to generate the data and then set `test_data` to the stdout of that command.

If `test_data` is set in advance (e.g., with `-e test_data=1`), then we don't bother running the command and we just use `test_data` verbatim.